# Bash - Shift-Tab shortcut

Tags: bash, keyboard-shortcuts

How to bind <kbd>Shift-Tab</kbd> keyboard shortcut to an action in Bash?

I tried to discover key code of <kbd>Shift-Tab</kbd> combination by

```
# sed -n l
^[[Z
\033[Z$
^C
```

and

```
# read a ; echo $a | hexdump -cC
^[[Z
0000000 033   [   Z  \n
00000000  1b 5b 5a 0a                                       |.[Z.|
00000004
```

Based on that I assume the key code is `\e[Z`. So `bind "\e[Z":menu-complete-backward` should do the trick. However it binds the action to <kbd>\</kbd>.

```
$ bind -p > bind.before
$ bind "\e[Z":menu-complete-backward
$ bind -p > bind.after
$ diff -y  --suppress-common-lines bind.before bind.after
# menu-complete-backward (not bound)                          | "\\": menu-complete-backward
"\\": self-insert                                             <
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try single-quoting the parameter:

```
bind '"\e[Z":menu-complete-backward'
```